# Validity of visual proof for surface area of sphere

Tags: calculus, geometry, area

I came across a visual proof for the surface area of a sphere in this gif (https://tenor.com/view/sphere-area-calculus-gif-7387824) but felt dubious about the process of "flattening" the sphere. Specifically, I am wondering whether anyone can describe the flattening process and justify why it is (or isn't) area preserving, or whether anyone can find some reference to this proof in the literature.

Comment: You should have a look at this video by 3B1B : https://youtu.be/VYQVlVoWoPY
It includes a "false proof" that the surface area of the surface is $\pi^2 R^2$, flattening the sphere in a similar way.

Comment: I watched the video and the proof in the gif seems to be more akin to the "correct" area preserving wedges that grow according to a sine curve (https://youtu.be/VYQVlVoWoPY?t=732) that yield the true answer. Wouldn't this lend credence to the visual proof then?

Comment: No, the take of this video is "do not trust blindly a visual proof" (pun intended). Even if the sine curve yields the correct answer, it's not a proof.

Answer (score 1):

A sphere of radius $R$ has Gaussian curvature equal to $1/R^2$. Any piece of a plane has Gaussian curvature equal to zero. Therefore, it is impossible to "flatten" the sphere without inflicting "severe" damage.

However, it is not entirely clear whether a global "flattening" process that doesn't change the surface area may be employed. The "visual proof" that you refer to hardly constitutes a proof, in my opinion.

Comment: You cut the sphere, locally flatten it and then add up the area contriubs

Comment: Locally flattening  is merely an expression of the fact that it is a (smooth) manifold. This, however, does not prove the formula itself. The "visual nonsense" referred to above is a global flattening, apparently.

Comment: Sure, my point was simply that, it would be possible, to proceed  in deriving a formula for area of a sphere by a method which involves local flattening

Comment: Agreed, completely. That's how we calculate the area of a two dimensional manifold.

Comment: You should be dubious about an animation such as this.  You can hide all kinds of trickery in an animation.  I also don't think it is particularly enlighting.  It is not a visual proof at all.  It shows you how to arrive at an integral that will indeed give you the surface area, but there are so ways many to set up an integral that will return the surface area of a sphere.  
 
If you want a visual proof then look at Archimedes hat box.

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedesHat-BoxTheorem.html